# Menu hierarchy in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to organize buttons in CCMenu so that they function like any menu out there? For example this browser's File, Edit, View, etc..

What I'm using now is the standard:

```
CCMenu *selectMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: item1, item2... nil];
[selectMenu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:15];
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(winSize.width / 2.0, winSize.height/1.035);
[selectMenu setPosition:topLeft];
[self addChild:selectMenu];
```

This is working, but I have too many buttons to align in one row, so hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you will have to create the submenu when the user click the menu item.

Something like this:

```
CCMenu *menu = nil;

    CCMenuItem *item = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Edit" block:^(id sender) {

        CCMenu *submenu = nil;

        CCMenuItem *subitem = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"SubItem" block:^(id sender) {
            //Do Stuff here
            [submenu removeFromParent];
        }];

        CCMenuItem *subitem2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"CloseSubMenu" block:^(id sender) {

            [submenu removeFromParent];
        }];

        submenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:subitem,subitem2, nil];

        [menu addChild:submenu];

    } ];

    menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item, nil];

    [self addChild:menu];
```

You still have to set the positions to make sure it looks ok on the screen.